# unequal thicknesses of \bottomrule and \toprule

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have a table as below, the problem is the difference in thickness/boldness between `\toprule` and `\bottomrule`. Is there a way to get around this problem? Many thanks in advance.

[image]

```
   \documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,filecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newcommand{\etal}{{\sl et al. }}
\newcommand{\argmax}{\operatornamewithlimits{argmax}}
\newcommand{\iid}{\stackrel{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}


\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{appendix}

%\pdfminorversion=4
% NOTE: To produce blinded version, replace "0" with "1" below.
\newcommand{\blind}{1}

% DON'T change margins - should be 1 inch all around.
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.5in}%
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.5in}%
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}%
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.3in}%
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.8in}%

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \footnotesize
    %\scriptsize
    \centering 
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{l*{9}{R}}
         \toprule
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{GLM1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{GLM2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{GLM3} \\ \midrule 
        Variables & BchMk & CCP.0 & CCP.1 & BchMk & CCP.0 & CCP.1 & BchMk & CCP.0 & CCP.1\\ %\midrule
        \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-8} \cmidrule(lr){9-10}
        \addlinespace
        %\multicolumn{10}{l}{\textbf{Panel A: ~~ GLM(1)} - Model with Networth } \\ 
        %\addlinespace
        Gender & 0.95 &  0.97 & 0.97 & 0.94$^{*}$ &  0.97 & 0.96 & 0.95 & 0.97 & 0.97 \\ 
    
        %\midrule
        \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-8}\cmidrule(lr){9-10}
        Observations & 26,212 & 21,184 & 5,029 & 26,212 & 21,184 & 5,029 & 26,212 & 21,184 & 5,029 \\  
        \bottomrule
        \addlinespace
        \multicolumn{10}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\footnotesize 
            Note: }\\
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{GLM models}
    \label{tab:GLM Results}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
    \footnotesize
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{
            @{\extracolsep{\fill}} l cccc
        }
        \toprule
        Variable   &  \multicolumn{4}{c}{Factor} \\ 
        \cmidrule{2-5}
        & BchMk &   CCP.0 & CCP.1 & X2-test\\
        \cmidrule{2-5}
        Gender   & 76.27\% & 75.32\% & 80.31\%  & p-value $<$ 2.2e-16 \\
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Continuous}\\
        \cmidrule{2-5}
        & BchMk &   CCP.0 & CCP.1 & t-test\\
        \cmidrule{2-5}
        Age & 53.9  &  53.46 &  55.72 &  2.26***\\
        & (14.28) & (14.07) & (15.01) &  (0.21)\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    
    \smallskip  
    Note: 
    \caption{Summary statistics}
    \label{tab:SampleDescription}
    
\end{table}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried zooming in and out? This often comes from rounding errors on screen. You can also try to print it on paper to see if the effect is still there.

Comment: Off-topic: I would replace the five `\addtolength` drectives with the single instruction `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}`.

Comment: It's definitely a previewer issue. Besides Mico's recommendation, you should also note that `\sl` has been deprecated for 30 years, and it should be `\newcommand{\etal}{\textsl{et al.\@}}`; also `hyperref` should be loaded last, `\operatornamewithlimits` should be `\operatorname*` and `\iid` is better defined as `\overset{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim}`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue cannot be reproduced and is likely due to the previewer raster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\specialrule{.8pt}{2pt}{2pt}` command instead of `\toprule` or `\bottomrule` as you will have flexibility of controlling thickness of line/rule.

Follow the syntax:

```
\specialrule{<thickness>}{<abovespace>}{<belowspace>}
```